# apex:input with oncomplete

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I have an input number and a button which performs an action on the input, and it is working nicely:

```
<apex:input type="number" value="{!addCount}"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!addRows}" value="Generate Participants" rerender="messages, documents"/>
```

Now I would like to put an onchange into the  and remove the buttons.

```
<apex:input type="number" value="{!addCount}" onchange="addRows"/>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!addRows}" name="addRows" rerender="messages, documents"/>
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually invoke the function for `onchange` attributes by using parentheses (`()`).

**No Good**

```
<apex:input onchange="someMethod" ... />
```

**Good**

```
<apex:input onchange="someMethod();" ... />
```

Note that if you want this event to fire every time you hit a key, you should probably switch from `onchange` to `onkeyup`.